# Is there a way to choose precisely where to add a vertex?

Tags: vertices

I work for a construction company and I want to create a topography/ground level for a site that is not flat. I have imported an image as plane with an over-layed a pdf screenshot of the site with the survey levels included.

I want to be able to place a vertex on each of these points to allow me then to adjust the height for each point. This is rhw image I'm working with.[image]Subdivision only seems to let me place more vertices on regular points.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you convert the PDF to SVG (if it contains vector data) and import the SVG into Blender?

Comment: Also do you have access to the actual topographical data from this site? Blender has several addons that can import topological data in several forms and convert it to a mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Just enable add-on `Add mesh: Extra objects`:
[image]

For now, you'll see a single vert option in `add` menu:
So, if you want to place vertex in specific position - just use `shift + right mouse button` hotkey to place your cursor in desired place and add the vertex.

[image]